# $(ax^2 - b^2)/ (cx^2 + dx + e)$ - Algebraic Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$\frac{ax^2 - b^2}{cx^2 + dx + e} = \frac{3x-2}{4x - 1},$$
find the values of the constants $a, b, c, d$ and $e$. So far I've tried to put the numerator and denominator into brackets and trying to cancel out from there, but I can't really factorize them.

Comment: I've tried to put the numerator and denominator into brackets and trying to cancel out from there, but I can't really factorize them

Comment: Try with $a=9$ and $b=2$

Comment: Where did you get these values from? this is the thing i need help with.

Comment: @ShayanC see my answer for clarification on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$ax^2-b^2=(x\sqrt{a}+b)(x\sqrt{a}-b)$$
Since one of these is $3x-2$, we can safely take that $a=9, b=\pm2$ (it doesn't matter which), as the other bracket must be $(3x+2)$.

Then the other side has $$(3x+2)(4x-1)=12x^2+5x-2$$
so $c=12, d=5, e=-2$